# jQuery UI Open Dialog run Function

Tags: jquery, time, jquery-selectors

This is the gist of what I am trying to accomplish with this code. 
I want to select an HOUR ahead, which this code Does do that, it just selects 4 items down. BUT my major problem is, say if someone selects 11:30pm, or 12 midnight, my .NEXT() code doesn't work... Is there a better solution for this?

```
$('.startTime222').change(function() {
   adjustTime = $(".startTime option:selected").next().next().next().next().val(); 
});

<select name="startTime" class="startTime222 required" id="startTime2" >
   <option value="00:00:00">12:00am</option>
   <option value="00:15:00">12:15am</option>
   <option value="00:30:00">12:30am</option>
   <option value="00:45:00">12:45am</option>
   <option value="01:00:00">1:00am</option>
   <option value="01:15:00">1:15am</option>
   <option value="01:30:00">1:30am</option>
   <option value="01:45:00">1:45am</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the suggestion to heart, Store the adjust time as a separate attribute on the option. This way you still have access to the time selected as well as the adjusted time. You no longer have to move forward four children since both values are now accessible.

```
$('.startTime222').change(function() {
   adjustTime = $(".startTime option:selected").attr("data-adjust");
});

<select name="startTime" class="startTime222 required" id="startTime2" >
   <option value="00:00:00" data-adjust="01:00:00">12:00am</option>
   <option value="00:15:00" data-adjust="01:15:00">12:15am</option>
   <option value="00:30:00" data-adjust="01:30:00">12:30am</option>
   <option value="00:45:00" data-adjust="01:45:00">12:45am</option>
   <option value="01:00:00" data-adjust="02:00:00">1:00am</option>
   <option value="01:15:00" data-adjust="02:15:00">1:15am</option>
   <option value="01:30:00" data-adjust="02:30:00">1:30am</option>
   <option value="01:45:00" data-adjust="02:45:00">1:45am</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Comment: You could alternatively add data-adjust="01:00:00" attributes to each option if you are relying on the value attribute matching the text for the start time and are only using the adjustment for a default end time. Instead of using .val() in the text, then, use .attr('date-adjust').

Comment: I don't get your response... how does this solve the problem when it reaches 12 midnight?

Comment: I think what JoeRobich intended is that if the user chooses the <option>12:00am</option>, you'd have data in the <option> itself that gives you the +1hr without having to calculate it dynamically. <option value="00:00:00" data-adjust="01:00:00">12:00am</option>. adjustTime = $(".startTime option:selected").attr('data-adjust'); will give you an adjustTime of "01:00:00".

Comment: I updated my answer with druttka's suggestion. There is no need to move next anymore, so if they choose 11:45pm you will not error.